# Console Error: .format is not a function - date formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In my code this error started to appear > causing the app to not run correctly.

I am trying to figure /or find what `js` file /or library is missing /or not loading properly - i am not getting any error that pointing that.
in order for that to run correctly:

```
 var displayDateForSorting = new Date(result.DM).format("M/d/yy");
```

**This error appear in Google chrome Console:**

> Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).format is not a function

What can I do i order for that error to not appear?

---

I found what was missing in my app- the `.format` was taken from MicrosoftAjax (old library) I add it it via nuget and .format now working!

Comment: The `Date` object has no `format()` function.

Comment: ...nor is one added by jQuery or jQuery UI. But if you do your research, and/or [search](/help/searching) here on SO, you'll find that every conceivable question about formatting dates has been addressed on the web and/or by SO answers.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Thanks. i know that. but this line of code has worked before

Comment: It's possible you're thinking of the `moment.js` library, but even that uses `moment.format()`

Comment: @E.Meir: Well, then you changed something. So look at what you changed. **We** can't help, as -- again -- whatever `format` function you used to be using, it isn't part of the JavaScript standard lib, jQuery, or jQuery UI.

Comment: I did Search nd saw posts on Stackoverflow- but didn't find one that using this keyword `.format`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OK Thanks. just wanted to confirm this-

Comment: I found what was missing in my app- the `.format` the was used was taken from MicrosoftAjax (old library) i add it it via nuget and `.format` now working!

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MicrosoftAjax/

Answer (score -2):

You could format your date in following way..

```
var myDate = new Date("February 3, 2001");  
var myDate = new Date("February 3 2001");  
document.write((myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + myDate.getDate() + "-" + myDate.getFullYear());  
document.write("<br/>");  
document.write((myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + myDate.getDate() + "/" + myDate.getFullYear());  

//Output:  
// 2-3-2001  
// 2/3/2001
```

For more information..[Official Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/date-and-time-strings-javascript)

Comment: Thanks- but i don't want to implement a new solution, i want to make the existing code working.